# Why does dplyr recode generate error when recoding to NA but not NaN

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm recoding with dplyr. I'm getting an error when I recode a value to NA, but not NaN. Here's an example:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(var=recode(var,`2`=0,`3`=NaN))
```

Works fine, whereas

```
df <- df %>% mutate(var=recode(var,`2`=0,`3`=NA))
```

gives me the following error:

```
Error: Vector 2 must be a double vector, not a logical vector
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running the code you get this error

```
tibble(var = rep(2:3, 4)) %>% 
 mutate(var=recode(var,`2`=0,`3`=NA)) 
# Error: Vector 2 must be a double vector, not a logical vector
```

This is because `NA` is logical, but `recode` is expecting a double

```
class(NA)
# [1] "logical"
```

You can use `NA_real_` instead, since that's a double

```
class(NA_real_)
# [1] "numeric"
is.double(NA_real_)
# [1] TRUE

tibble(var = rep(2:3, 4)) %>% 
 mutate(var=recode(var,`2`=0,`3`=NA_real_)) 
#     var
#   <dbl>
# 1     0
# 2    NA
# 3     0
# 4    NA
# 5     0
# 6    NA
# 7     0
# 8    NA
```

For why it's expecting a double, see `?recode`

> All replacements must be the same type, and must have either length
>   one or the same length as .x.

I think the reason this is unexpected is because base functions like `c` don't care if the elements are of the same type and will just convert upwards anyway. So this works:

```
c(1, NA, 3)
```

Because for the `c` function:

> The output type is determined from the highest type of the components
>   in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex <
>   character < list < expression

Comment: Thanks! I chose this answer because I wanted to recode my variables all in one go. Never thought about NA's type, precisely for the reason you identified...

Answer (score 3):

An option to change a specific value to `NA` is `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(var = na_if(var, 3))
```

---

With `recode`, @IceCreamToucan's answer is great, but if we want to change it automatically between `integer/numeric`, we can still do it based on the property of `NA` in multiplication (to return NA, but it would change the type automatically)

```
df %>% 
    mutate(var = recode(var,`2`=0,`3`=NA* var[!is.na(var)][1]))
#    var
#1   0
#2  NA
#3   4
#4   5
#5  NA
```

It can be other functions as well which return `NA`

```
df %>%
      mutate(var = recode(var,`2`=0,`3`= max(var[1], NA)))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(var = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 3))
```